# Where can I learn more about neural network optimization?

Tags: neural-networks

I have limited experience with matlab's nn toolbox but I can manage to train a network and get it to generate decent results. However, I have no idea how many hidden layers, hidden nodes, which transfer function for each layer, and which training method to use.

I tried searching online for tutorials but all of it seems really vague and subjective. Can someone direct me to any good websites?